# Consolidate / Manipulate array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like the following:

```
[{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-01-03"
},{
  animal: "dog",
  dateString: "2017-02-05"
},{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-03-04"
}]
```

and I'd like to create a new array that looks like:

```
[{
  animal: "cat",
  values: [
    "2017-01-03",
    "2017-03-04"
  ]
},{
  animal: "dog",
  values: [
    "2017-02-05"
  ]
}]
```

How can I consolidate the individual object properties into an array of values?

Comment: array reduce function is a popular method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without lodash/ramda u can do

```
const a = [
  {
    animal: 'cat',
    dateString: '2017-01-03'
  }, {
    animal: 'dog',
    dateString: '2017-02-05'
  }, {
    animal: 'cat',
    dateString: '2017-03-04'
  }
]

const b = Object.values(a.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (a[b.animal]) {
    a[b.animal].values.push(b.dateString)
  } else {
    a[b.animal] = {animal: b.animal, values: [b.dateString]}
  }
  return a
}, {}))
```

Comment: vscode complains about the following on "Object.values":
[ts] Property 'values' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.

Comment: nm.  I had to change this to "(<any>Object)" so that typescript wouldn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not tagged only JS, try this (Vanilla JS)

```
    var x = [{
        animal: "cat",
        dateString: "2017-01-03"
     },{
        animal: "dog",
        dateString: "2017-02-05"
     },{
        animal: "cat",
        dateString: "2017-03-04"
    }];

    let usedKeys = [];
    let finalArray = [];

    for(var z = 0; z < x.length ; z++)
    {
       if(usedKeys.indexOf(x[z]['animal']) == '-1')
       {
           usedKeys.push(x[z]['animal']);
           finalArray.push({'animal':x[z]['animal'] , 'values':[x[z]['dateString']]});
       }
       else
       {
           let targetIndex = usedKeys.indexOf(x[z]['animal']);
           finalArray[targetIndex]['values'].push(x[z]['dateString']);
       }
    }

console.log(finalArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to double sort your array.

```
var arr = [{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-01-03"
},{
  animal: "dog",
  dateString: "2017-02-05"
},{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-03-04"
}];

var sorted = [];

arr.forEach(function callback(arrVal, index1, array1) {
   sorted.forEach(function callback(sortVal, index2, array2) {
      if (arrVal == sortVal) {
         sorted[index2].values.push(arrVal.dateString);
      } else {
         sorted.push({animal: arr[index1].animal, values: [arr[index1].dateString]});
      }
   });
});
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Wouldn't the nested forEach loops be a performance concern for large arrays?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by large. In this case in a greater degree performance depends on the scatteredness of the first unsorted array. If you want to improve performance then you should look at your database query to get sorted data at once.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data=[{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-01-03"
},{
  animal: "dog",
  dateString: "2017-02-05"
},{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-03-04"
}]

var ans = data.reduce(function(accumulator, element) {
var elementInAccumulator = accumulator[element.animal]
if(elementInAccumulator) {
  if(Array.isArray(elementInAccumulator.values)) {
    elementInAccumulator.values.push(element.dateString)
  }
  else {
  var arr=[]
  
  arr.push(elementInAccumulator.dateString)
  arr.push(element.dateString)
  elementInAccumulator.values= arr
  delete(elementInAccumulator.dateString)
  }
}
else {
  accumulator[element.animal] = element
}
return accumulator
}, {})
console.log(Object.keys(ans).map(function(element) {
  return ans[element]
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to store your object in a new object where values will be grouped on based on animal name. Then, use `Object.values` to get the result.

```js
var data = [{ animal: "cat", dateString: "2017-01-03" },{ animal: "dog", dateString: "2017-02-05" },{ animal: "cat", dateString: "2017-03-04" }];

var result = data.reduce((o, {animal, dateString}) => {
  o[animal] ? o[animal].values.push(dateString) : o[animal] = {animal, values: [dateString]}
  return o;
},{});

var output = Object.values(result);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you first create a new, empty array and a `for-loop`. From there you either create a brand new object with of the animal type or just push the `dateString` value of the other if it does:

```js
const animals = [{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-01-03"
}, {
  animal: "dog",
  dateString: "2017-02-05"
}, {
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-03-04"
}];

const combined = [];

for (let i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
  const { animal, dateString } = animals[i];
  
  const animalIndex = combined.findIndex(obj => {
    return obj['animal'] === animal;
  });
  
  if (animalIndex === -1) {
    combined.push({ animal, values: [dateString] });
  } else {
    combined[animalIndex]['values'].push(dateString);
  }
}

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simply iterate the array and build a result by mapping each animal to and object that contains its properties, e.g. `{'cat': {'animal': 'cat', 'values': ["2017-01-03"]}}`. When we're done, we'll extract only the values:

```js
const arr = [{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-01-03"
},{
  animal: "dog",
  dateString: "2017-02-05"
},{
  animal: "cat",
  dateString: "2017-03-04"
}]

let res=  {}
arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (res[obj.animal]) {
    res[obj.animal].values.push(obj.dateString)
  } else {
    res[obj.animal] = {animal: obj.animal, values: [obj.dateString]}
  }
})

res = Object.values(res)
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```